# Kinect: interaction pattern

Tags: interface, kinect

I'm on kinect coding with OpenNI, and i'm really enthusiastic of this new device!

I'm looking for some interaction pattern, like how to control movement of an actor in a 3d space.

anyone have some advice?

Comment: I think you'll have to be more specific about what kind of interactions you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old, but as technology has caught up to this question, OpenNI has since developed a wrapper that you can use for Unity to basically drag and drop onto a biped and control with the Kinect. Also on coding for fun they have wrappers for the UDK as well. So yes, now you can, the information is out there.